# Factors and Subfactors in R

Tags: r

If I have the following data frame of factors and their subfactors. How can I extract information like the food the dog eats and the food that cat eats in R?

```
factors subfactors
dog          biscuit
dog          chicken
dog          chicken
cat          milk
cat          soup
dog          pedigree
```

Expected Output:

```
dog: biscuit,chicken,pedigree
cat: milk,soup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Ate = paste(unique(subfactors), collapse = ", ")), by = factors]


##    factors                        Ate
## 1:     dog biscuit, chicken, pedigree
## 2:     cat                 milk, soup
```

A more `data.table` way of doing this will be

```
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ", ")), by = factors]
```

You can also do this with base R, (although `data.table` is always preferable if you have a big data set)

```
aggregate(subfactors ~ factors, df, function (x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ", "))

##   factors                 subfactors
## 1     cat                 milk, soup
## 2     dog biscuit, chicken, pedigree
```

Comment: but chicken is coming twice as per the edit question,I just need it once.

Comment: I've added a base R solution if you prefer doing it without additional packages

Comment: if there is any blank space in one of the subfactors, how to eliminate it?

Comment: Could do `setDT(df)[, list(Ate = paste(unique(subfactors[subfactors != ""]), collapse = ", ")), by = factors]`

Comment: further, the number of subfactors for each factor,can it be determined?

Comment: we can also use paste(shQuote(unique(subfactors, type="cmd")), collapse=", ")

Comment: for number of subfactors `setDT(df)[, list(Ate = length(unique(subfactors[subfactors != ""]))), by = factors]`

Comment: after forming the table, how do i get access to each of the words,say in case of matching? I want to match chicken with stringsfromanother data frame

Comment: i'd guess you''ll ave to match them before the aggregation and then add another column in the aggregation process. Anyway, if you have some new questions, it is better to post a new question than adding them in comments

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean basic indexing????

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'factors subfactors
dog          biscuit
dog          chicken
cat          milk
cat          soup
dog          pedigree')

df[df$factors == 'dog', "subfactors"]
df[df$factors == 'cat', "subfactors"]
```

Or maybe split into a list:

```
split(df$subfactors, df$factors)
```

Comment: what if there are around 20 factors? This was just a reproducible example.

Comment: BTW: This was NOT a reproducible example!

Comment: split works..but if one subfactor occurs twice,it shows it twice which is not wanted.

Comment: @user2458552 Please add expected output to your question based on data supplied.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqldf`:

```
#reproducible data
df <- read.table(text = "factors subfactors
dog          biscuit
dog          chicken
dog          chicken
cat          milk
cat          soup
dog          pedigree",header=TRUE,as.is=TRUE)

library(sqldf)

sqldf("SELECT factors, GROUP_CONCAT(subfactors) AS Food
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT factors, subfactors
              FROM df)
       GROUP BY factors")

#output
#   factors                     Food
# 1     cat                milk,soup
# 2     dog biscuit,chicken,pedigree
```

Answer (score 0):

A list output for `subfactors`:

```
 aggregate(subfactors~factors,df,FUN=unique)
 factors                 subfactors
1     cat                 milk, soup
2     dog biscuit, chicken, pedigree
```

or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
group_by(factors) %>% #grouping variable
summarise(subfactors=paste(unique(subfactors),collapse=","))
```